# Law of chemical equivalence

Tags: titration

In this reaction,
$$\ce{KIO_3 + KI -> I_2}$$ 
According to law of chemical equivalence, shouldn't $m_{eq}$ of $\ce{KIO_3}$ = $m_{eq}$ of $\ce{KI}$ = $m_{eq}$ of $\ce{I_2}$?
However, the book that I was reading from, said:
Total $m_{eq}$. of $\ce{I_2}$ = $m_{eq}$ of $\ce{I_2}$ (from $\ce{KIO_3}$) + $m_{eq}$ of $\ce{I_2}$ (from $\ce{KI}$).
Why is it so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Reaction is a Disproportionation Reaction, that is, a reaction involving both oxidation and reduction of a single species, in this case : Iodine. This is not one reaction but a combination of two reactions:
$$\ce{KIO3 -> I2}$$
And
$$\ce{KI -> I2}$$
Therefore, by applying law of chemical equivalence in both reactions and adding the equations :

$m_{eq}$ of $\ce{I_2}$ (from both reactions) = $m_{eq}$ of $\ce{I_2}$ (from $\ce{KIO3}$) + $m_{eq}$ of $\ce{I_2}$ (from $\ce{KI}$)

Comment: Welcome to chem.SE! You might also write the reactions completely to avoid future confusions from the readers of this answer.

Comment: Technically it is a comproportionation (two different oxidation states going to the same oxidation state), not a disproportionation (the same oxidation state going to different oxidation states, such as $\ce{Cl2 -> Cl- + OCl-}$. I think it's a trivial matter though.